# NodeJS : How to reset the cache-control for the public folder after the user authentication

Tags: node.js, cache-control

Actually the cache-control for the folder «public» is fixed by :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
```

I would like to reset the maxAge to 0 when the user is not authenticated or expired session.

Is there a way to do it ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: donot pass maxAge

Comment: Thx for you reply, k but in this case is there a way to update the max age for the public folder when the user is authenticated ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this hope this might work for you

```
 if(user === authenticated){
    app.use('/public/images/icons', static('public/images/icons', 12345));
    app.use('/public/images/', static('public/images', 1234567);
    etc.  
    }
//function declaration 
 function static(dirname, age) {
            return express.static(path.join(__dirname, dirname), { maxAge: age });
        }
```

Comment: Error excepted, it doesn't work ... the maxAge still fix to 0 (checked in the «Response Headers»). May be there is a way to catch the css request and update set maxAge header ? I tried with app.get('/public/*',function ........ but without success

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Regarding my original request :

```
function userConnect(req, res){ 
...
res.setHeader('Clear-Site-Data', '"cache", "storage"');
....
```

But now, I'm using :

```
const serverStarted = moment().unix();
....
app.get("*",function(req, res, next){
  if (req.session&&req.session.serverStarted!=serverStarted) {
    res.setHeader('Clear-Site-Data', '"cache", "storage"');
    req.session.serverStarted = serverStarted;
  }
  next();
})
```